# The same Python script no error in Spyder but error in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, spyder

I am just running a very simple script. It is working in Spyder but not in Sublime Text, I am so confused:

```
import pandas as pd

iris_df = pd.read_csv("data/iris.data")
```

Error in Sublime Text:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'data/iris.data' does not exist: b'data/iris.data'
```

Comment: programs may run code in different folders (so called `"Current Working Directory"` - shortly `"cwd"`) and they may search for `data/iris.data` in different folders - so better use `/full/path/to/data/iris.data`

Comment: Using a relative file path can cause issues because it may be relative to the wrong location. Better use an absolute path.

Comment: As an alternative to using absolute paths you can also modify the `sublime-build` file to include a `working_dir` key that sets the appropriate location so that relative paths will work. The `Python.sublime-build` that ships with Sublime doesn't include that key by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spyder, it may set to current working directly., so specifying the file name would be enough to execute the code. Whereas when you run from sublime, Atom etc.., you need to specify the complete file path.